# How to install npm modules for nuxt.js on server without internet connection

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'am developing a universal app with nuxt js. Apperently the server does not have a network connection to the internet. Is is possible to build the application with all it's depedencies or manual install the dependecies?

Best regards,

Ian

Comment: You can't install something from the internet if you don't have an internet connection? How are you even planning on using a server without an internet connection?

Comment: @MoltasDev intranet server. Only available when you are at the office.

Comment: `npm run generate` together with the `mode: 'spa'` in the nuxt.config.js should to the trick. This will create a dist folder with one single index entry and all the necessary dependencies in the output js chunks (done by the internal webpack plugin from nuxt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general for Node.js, unless native extensions are used, you can just install Node.js on the target server, then copy over your `node_modules` directory.

If there are native extensions, get your hands on an internet-connected machine with a similar architecture (OS and processor) and Node.js version as your deployment target, run `npm i`/`yarn` there and copy over *that* `node_modules` directory.

I haven't used Nuxt.js, though, so YMMV there.